# MySQL query for system specs such as installed RAM or CPUs

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to retrieve information about the system a MySQL server is running on. I am interested in getting the number of logical cores. Is that possible?

I ran `SHOW VARIABLES;` but there is no such info there. I am having access to the server using `PDO` - is there a way to retrieve metadata from the connection or a statement that might hold this kind of data?

**Edit:** I should probably add the information that the two systems *MySQL-Server* and *Client* (which uses PHP from another host) are two *physically separated* systems, so I only have access via MySQL-queries.

Comment: I'm not sure that information can be found through MySQL. You can see some info in `STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES`, but those are mostly mysql-centric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was doing a little more research on the topic and as of today (Nov '16), it **can't** be done the way I had required it.

Comment: Executing `system cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores" | wc -l` will return number of CPU cores on the server machine. Yes, this is a valid MySQL query, you can copy paste it into MySQL **terminal**. However, I wouldn't use MySQL to retrieve system information.

Comment: @Mjh that works well but unfortunately **only** through the CLI client (i.e. not by a query).

Comment: Yep, you're right, for some reason I thought it might be wrapped in a stored procedure. It looks like sys_exec UDF would be the way to deal with this, but that in itself is a problem to install and handle.

Comment: I had a similar thing, but for CPU architecture; found this in `version_compile_machine` variable (assuming the compile arch matches the running arch).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out phpSysInfo @ http://phpsysinfo.github.io/phpsysinfo/

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear, please see the edit :)

Comment: In that case I would have to agree with aynber's comment.  Can you access your MySQL server using SNMP?  If so then you could possibly get the info using that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use SNMP or any other additional software for that matter.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on ubuntu system, try these commands

```
top // for CUP
free -m // for RAM
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to obtain the information through a MySQL-query.